# macOS standard keyboard shortcuts for tabbing between windows

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager

Are there any key combinations standards for tabbing between windows **within an application**?  For example, in the Safari web browser: CTRL-TAB will cycle through the open tabs.  It would be nice if this was

If not, I am wondering if there is a clever technique to implement such a feature (automator?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems to be conflating two things: cycling through tabs of a window and cycling through windows of an application.

- <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>` grave</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>` grave</kbd> will cycle through windows in an application.
  This works for virtually all applications.
- <kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd><kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> will cycle through tabs in a window.
  This works for all applications which implement macOS Sierra's standard tab framework or implement this keyboard shortcut for their own tabs (which almost all tab-supporting apps do).